# How to inherit parameters from yaml template

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-yaml

Is there a better way of referencing a base template without duplicating parameters?

I have a base yaml template...

```
parameters:
  name: buildapp1
  type: boolean
  name: buildapp2
  type: boolean
  name: buildapp3
  type: boolean
```

...and need to reference it from multiple pipelines:

```
parameters:
  name: buildapp1
  type: boolean
  name: buildapp2
  type: boolean
  name: buildapp3
  type: boolean

- template: basetemplate.yaml
  parameters:
    buildapp1: ${{ parameters.buildapp1 }}
    buildapp2: ${{ parameters.buildapp2 }}
    buildapp3: ${{ parameters.buildapp3 }}
```

UPDATE:

If I could specify a UI varaible 'environment' and then resolve that on queue time that would work great.

I have tried the following but it results in "unexpected value".

```
varaibles:
  - template: $(environment).yaml
  - template: ${{ environment }}.yaml
```

Answer (score 0):

---

After updated question:

---

Pipeline:

```
parameters:
  - name: environment
    type: string
    displayName: To which environment does the pipeline have to run?
    default: temp1
    values: 
      - temp1
      - temp2

steps:
  - template: ${{ parameters.environment }}.yml
```

Result after selecting temp1

[image]

---

Before question update

---

One way to do it is via variables.

### Variable scopes

In the YAML file, you can set a variable at various scopes:

At the root level, to make it available to all jobs in the pipeline.
At the stage level, to make it available only to a specific stage.
At the job level, to make it available only to a specific job.
When a variable is defined at the top of a YAML, it will be available to all jobs and stages in the pipeline and is a global variable. Global variables defined in a YAML are not visible in the pipeline settings UI.

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#variable-scopes

azure-pipeline.yml

```
trigger:
  - none

parameters:
  - name: parA
    type: string
    default: "A"
  - name: parB
    type: string
    default: "B"

variables:
  parA : ${{ parameters.parA }}
  parB : ${{ parameters.parB }}

steps:
  - template: temp1.yml
  - template: temp2.yml
```

temp1.yml → first template

```
steps:
  - bash: echo $(parA)
    displayName: 'Template 1'
```

temp2.yml → second template

```
steps:
  - bash: echo $(parB)
    displayName: 'Template 2'
```

Result:

Template 1:

[image]

Template 2:

[image]

Comment: Thank you

If I can specify a ui variable 'environment' and then resolve that variable at queue time that would work great.

I have tried the following but it gives "unexpected value"

variables:
  - template: $(environment).yaml
  - template: ${{ variables.environment }}.yaml

Comment: That looks a bit difficult as the template name is being resolved at compile time while the variables are resolved at runtime

Comment: @MartinNilsson: I have updated the solution with another scenario

Comment: Thank you. That is my current solution but i was hoping to remove that parameter

Comment: with above solution, you would be able to remove the duplicate parameters.

Comment: @MartinNilsson, does this correction `- template: ${{ parameters.environment }}.yml` resolves your issue?

Answer (score 0):

There is a way around this to eliminate the need for two [parameters/variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/process/templates?view=azure-devops&WT.mc_id=AZ-MVP-5004321#parameter-data-types)

I'd actually recommend just loading the parameter file as part of a job that contains the task. This way can be completely templated and parameter files scoped to the job, not to mention the benefit of parallel agents if desired.

It could look something like:

```
parameters:
- name: environmentObject
  type: object
  default: ['A','B']
jobs: 
- ${{ each environmentObject in parameters.environmentObjects }} :
    - template: echo.yml
      parameters: 
           environmentName: ${{ evnrionmentObject }}
```

echo.yml

```
parameters
- name: environmenName
  type: string
  default: ''

jobs:
- job: bash_${{parameters.environmentName}}
  steps:
      - bash: echo ${{parameters.environmentName}}
        displayName: 'Template ${{parameters.environmentName}}'
```

Comment: Thank you! This will work great to deploy multiple environments as seperate stages in a single pipeline. My initial idea was to create separate pipelines for each environment from the same yaml, but defining a hidden property/variable that is resolved at queue time is proving difficult.